# How do I run an Angular 2 Page in a Spring MVC Application?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, web

I want to have index.html from an angular 2 project to run as a welcome page of a Spring MVC application. 
The way I run the angular 2 is via `npm start`. If I load the index.html without doing `npm start`, components do not load properly.
 How will I be able to make index.html as the welcome page for my Spring MVC Project?

Edit: Added some more details.

The angular-seed project is loaded as is. I'm just trying to load the index.html from the angular-seed project. node modules have already been added and it runs perfectly with `npm start`.

As for my web.xml, I have the welcome file this way:

```
  <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>AngularContent/src/index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

And index.html has the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="AngularContent/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="AngularContent/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="AngularContent/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="AngularContent/src/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('AngularContent/src/main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need configure your src correctly, post some code is helpful

Comment: @Jaiwo99 Added codes. Let me know if you need anything more

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a same problem and I found proper solution lately.

Follow below steps to achieve our main goal, to run SPRINGMVC + Angular2 on a single server.

1. Create normal Dynamic web project.
2. Add all dependancy required for spring or user maven pom.xml
3. Open CMD, navigate to angular2 application. Hit command
   `npm install` to download node_modules and then `ng build` or use `ng build --prod` for production.This command will create a "dist" folder, copy all files including all folders.
4. Paste those files and folders into WebContent directory.
5. Last thing, you need to change basehref="./" in index.html.

Now you are ready to run server or you can deploy war file and serve it with tomcat or other servers.

visit [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42613222/6709592) if you want file structure for spring and angular 2!

Comment: 5) was very very useful.

Comment: Point 5 is great & most useful thing. It saved me.